# iOS - AVAssetExportSession unknown error -12769

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

It seems that AVFoundation cannot accept one of my videos. I really don't know why. It works with other videos, but not this one.

I'm not even modifying the video, I'm just doing a composition with the video track, and exporting it with the preset "AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality".

I get this error :

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000045a8e0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12769 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12769), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Do you know if there is something wrong in my code, or if the video is just not supported by AVFoundation ?

Here's the project on Github (it just exports the video to the camera roll) :

https://github.com/moonshaped/ExportSessionCrash

Or if you don't want to use Github :

Here's the video :

Dropbox link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/twgah26gqgsv9y9/localStoreTempVideoPath.mp4?dl=0

Or WeTransfer link : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8f8ab257068461a2c9a051542610725220170606122640/8d934c

And here's the code :

```
- (void)exportVideo:(AVAsset *)videoAsset
      videoDuration:(Float64)videoAssetDuration
                 to:(NSString *)resultPath{

    [Utilities deleteFileIfExists:resultPath];

    AVMutableComposition *mainComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mainComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    int timeScale = 100000;
    int videoDurationI = (int) (videoAssetDuration * (float) timeScale);
    CMTime videoDuration = CMTimeMake(videoDurationI, timeScale);
    CMTimeRange videoTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration);

    NSArray<AVAssetTrack *> *videoTracks = [videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];

    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:videoTimeRange
                                   ofTrack:videoTrack
                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                     error:nil];

    NSURL *outptVideoUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resultPath];
    self.exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mainComposition
                                                     presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

    self.exporter.outputURL = outptVideoUrl;
    self.exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    self.exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    [self.exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            switch (self.exporter.status) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
                    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"failed export"
                                                   reason:[self.exporter.error description]
                                                 userInfo:nil];
                }
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"cancelled export"
                                                   reason:@"Export cancelled"
                                                 userInfo:nil];

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
                    NSLog(@"Export finished");
                }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an experiment and come to this. If you reduce 1 or more millisecond from the videoTimeRange then it will work. Try replacing the below code block:

```
int timeScale = 100000;
Float64 seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([videoAsset duration]) - 0.001;
NSUInteger videoDurationI = (NSUInteger) (seconds * (float) timeScale);
CMTime videoDuration = CMTimeMake(videoDurationI, timeScale);
CMTimeRange videoTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

The device you are trying to test is not able to decode it. Please try it on some newer devices e.g. iPhone 6. I tested your media on iPad simulator iOS10.3 and it worked fine there so it must be something to do with encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply ! Can I ask which iPad simulator did you use ? I only have installed : iPad 2, iPad Air, iPad Air 2, iPad Pro, iPad retina. Currently testing with iPad Air 2 to see if it works. Thanks again

Comment: For me it still crashes with iPad Air 2 iOS 10.3. Can I also ask how dit you try please ? Was it with my code or something else ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried with iPad pro iOS10.3, there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Unfortunately I still have the crash with the simulator iPad Pro (9.7 inch) iOS 10.3.1 ... I have Xcode 8.3.3 and "Base SDK" set to Latest iOS (10.3) . Not sure what differences could exist between our project that would lead to this crash on my side.. Since I've tested it in my app project, I will try to make a new project and bundle the video to see if it works.

Comment: I also tried with an iphone 7 (real device) and it was crashing.. Does it work for you with older devices/simulators ? Maybe there's something wrong in my code or my project configuration, build settings..

Comment: On one of my older device like iPad4 it gives me following error:
_Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11855 "Cannot Decode" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Decode, NSUnderlyingError=0x155a8760 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12910 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The media data could not be decoded on this device.}_

Comment: Thanks ! It is not the same crash as me unfortunately. It is weird because I have the crash on every device on my side, so there should be a difference between our projects ? Are you sure you are testing with the exact same code ? Do you have the same export preset ? Because my code works with other presets, like "AVAssetExportPreset960x540". But I don't want to resize the video..

Comment: Thanks a lot again, I've created a public repository that you can test if you want : https://github.com/moonshaped/ExportSessionCrash . That would be really nice of you to test it if you can, and tell me if it works :)

Comment: I tried your repository. Now I can reproduce the exact same crash that you are having. I still think that there is something wrong with this video file. If you reduce 1 millisecond from the videoTimeRange then it works. Try replacing the below code block:

`int timeScale = 100000;
    Float64 seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([videoAsset duration]) - 0.001;
    NSUInteger videoDurationI = (NSUInteger) (seconds * (float) timeScale);
    CMTime videoDuration = CMTimeMake(videoDurationI, timeScale);
    CMTimeRange videoTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration);`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer ! It's funny because last Friday my coworker did the exact same thing as you and indeed it fixed the issue ;) ! We pushed the fix to prod (so that more users can test) but some of them are still experiencing the issue with their videos (that we don't have access to). Maybe we could remove more than 1 millisec, but not sure if that's a correct fix. Can you make another answer and I will mark your answer as accepted ? Cheers !

Comment: I made another answer. Thanks.